# How to rotate point label for radar chartJS?

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, radar-chart

ChartJS 4.3.0

[If I have a lot of data label is overlap as this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1E2A.png)

I want to change the direction according to the radial line.

Here is my config

```js
pointLabels: {
          font: {
            size: 14
          },
          callback: function (value, index, values) {
            var angle = (360 / values.length) * index; // Calculate the angle based on the index

            var radius = this.getDistanceFromCenterForValue(this.options.reverse ? this.max - value : value);

            var position = this.getPointPosition(angle, radius);

            var context = this.ctx;
            context.save();
            context.translate(position.x, position.y);
            context.rotate(angle * Math.PI / 180); // Rotate the label by converting angle to radians
            context.textAlign = 'center';
            context.textBaseline = 'middle';
            context.fillText(value, 0, 0);
            context.restore();

            return '';
          }
        }
```